# Why just including iostream.h makes executable weigh 1mb more?

Tags: c++, iostream

It is not even a "hello world", it is simply:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

which weighs 1080 kb. When I remove the iostream inclusion in the program to get

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

the executable's size becomes only 49 kb.
I just want to include iostream and maybe use only std::cout, but the size will be the whole megabyte again. So, where is the trouble and how do I fix it?
PS: I am using wxDevCpp with mingW and debugging info feature is off.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you really compile for release with optimizations on?

Comment: That's because you're paying for what you get. The I/O stream implementation is quite large, even if you "only" use `std::cout`.

Comment: It is normal that including iostream rises the size of the executable, specially considering it has templates and templates  are expensive in size.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with C++ or iostream, just with your compiler. With GCC 4.6.3 under Ubuntu the executable has 12kb, no matter if iostream has been included. And even `cout << "hello"` does not change size except a few bytes.

Comment: @t.niese I am not sure if there is release/debug business in wxDevCpp, is there?
Is there some kind of command for a compiler to not include unused functions/templates/classes?

Comment: @user3496846 _'Is there some kind of command for a compiler to not include unused functions/templates/classes?'_ That's already done by the linker, but since `std::cout` et al. are **instantiated** there, they **are used**.

Comment: @cnluzon that does not sound right, as far as I know templates are only compiled when it was used, called, instantiated or specialized, so it should have the opposite effect right?

Comment: @0xdeadbeef you are probably right about this, or at least the compiler seems to agree when I try it on my laptop now (executable being only marginally bigger when including `<iostream>` instantiating `std::cout` or not). There seem to be differences across compilers and operating systems in this though, which might be the reason why I thought this was an including templates issue rather than a compiler one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, where is the trouble and how do I fix it?

Including `<iostream>` instantiates the global variables `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::cerr`, and thus links in the whole c++ I/O library.

The only way to fix this, is not including `<iostream>`, if you don't need anything from there.

Comment: But what if I do not want to use anything but std::cout? Is there a way to include only std::cout?

Comment: Maybe more clearly: Yes, but std::cout needs much stuff itself to work

Comment: @user3496846 _'Is there a way to include only std::cout?'_ In short: No!

Comment: @deviantfan Yes? How? Explain please??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, maybe my comment is even more confusing. What i meant is that it is possible/trivial to leave not-used stuff outside, but cout needs much itself.

Comment: Standard says all objects (cin, cout, clog, cerr, wcin, wcout, wcerr, wclog) have to be created before the body of main begins execution.

Comment: @deviantfan , leaving not-used stuff outside sounds awesome, how do I do it?

Comment: @user3496846: You doesn´t seem to understand what everybody here tells you (different wording issues aside): There is no problem. If you´re using "just" cout in your code, cout itself will use many other things, which are using even more things themselves etc.etc.. "Just" cout => much stuff required => larger file required.

Comment: @deviantfan OK, I gotcha. I will get rid of it somehow then later. All good things, you helped me guys. Thanks!

Comment: @user3496846 To clarify: It wouldn't make a difference (at least not much), if you were able to control to instantiate only `std::cout`. All of the mentioned static variables are of the same class, and share the same code (which is what blows up your executable size).